# UnitTest should I have to use teardown and setup

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, xctestcase

I want to test such a class:

```
class Foo {
    var number: Int = 0
}
```

In the iOS unit test, normally test case should be:

```
class FooTests: XCTestCase {

    var foo: Foo!

    override func setUp() {
        foo = Foo()
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        foo = nil
    }

    func testAbc() {
        print(foo.number)
        foo.number = 10
    }

    func testBCD() {
        print(foo.number)
    }

}
```

Then how about

```
class FooTests: XCTestCase {

     let foo = Foo()

     func testAbc() {
        print(foo.number)
        foo.number = 10
    }

    func testBCD() {
        print(foo.number)
    }

}
```

I see the output are all 0 which means when each start test case the `foo` seems is initialised again. Just like use `setUp` and `tearDown`.

Are both way the same?

**EDIT**:
Thanks to @Anton 's answer, I even tested without `setUp` but with `tearDown`, then same as use both `setUp` and `tearDown`.

```
    var foo: Foo! = Foo()

    override func tearDown() {
        foo = nil
    }
```

Comment: There're `class`(`static`) and `instance` `setUp` and `tearDown` methods. `static` ones are called once, `instance` ones are called before and after **each** test. Reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestcase/understanding_setup_and_teardown_for_test_methods

Comment: https://qualitycoding.org/xctestcase-teardown/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They behaviors like same but have a difference. To understand the difference you can add to your test class init and deinit methods:

```
class Foo {
    var number: Int = 0

    init() {
        print("Init")
    }

    deinit {
        print("Deinit")
    }
}
```

Now you will see that at first case init and deinit invokes at each test.
Because setUp and tearDown is instance method and invokes before and after run the test.

But at second case init is invoked twice during create test suit. It happens because you use a default initializer for foo constant. It invokes during the initialization of Test Case which happens before run any test.

So, better to use the first option. Because if the instance under a test use some global state or have side effects then you may get flaky tests. They lives in memory in parallel.

[image: Diagram]

Comment: If like that the `number` should be changed to 10 in `testBCD`, right?

Comment: No. Because XCTest creates two instances of test class one for each test case. So you works with a copy of Foo instance at each test.

Comment: Hey @Anton, I got you. Acutally same functionality, just without tearDown, then release at the point of finished each test case. Thanks!

Comment: I even tested without `setUp` and with `tearDown`, both `init` and `deinit` were called twice. : )

Answer (score 7):

Note that

```
var foo: Foo! = Foo()

override func tearDown() {
    foo = nil
}
```

is still incorrect. The problem is that the Foo will be created when the test is instantiated. All tests are instantiated at once. So if there are 5 test cases in this suite, that means there will be 5 instances of FooTests, each with their own Foo. And all before any tests are run.

This can cause problems, particularly if Foo registers itself with a shared controller such as NotificationCenter.

Instead, do

```
private var foo: Foo!

override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()
    foo = Foo()
}

override func tearDown() {
    foo = nil
    super.tearDown()
}
```

This guarantees that `foo` will be created in the context of a running test case.

Comment: " And all before any tests are run." Do you mean the 5 instances are there 1 Just after typing the 5 test cases 2. Just after click the test button for `FooTests`(run all test cases) 3. Click any of the 5 test cases to run the test. (Even click one test case, there are 5 instances there already?) Thanks!

Comment: Yes. Even if you "run a single test," I'm pretty sure it will instantiate every single test first, then run the one you specified.